# Linking in a PHP echo with <li> tags

Tags: php, cakephp, echo

Earlier today I integrated the ability for my users to list several social profiles on their account on my website. Everything went off without a hitch but unfortunately I am now stuck on how to make the URLs the users input links because there is an `<li>` involved. The code I use to display the entry on their profile if information is provided is thus...

```
<?php
if($user['User']['fbcontact']!='')
{
  echo "<li>Facebook: <span>".h($user['User']['fbcontact'])."</span></li>";}
?>
```

So I know that there are several ways of doing echo links traditionally, but the `<li>` tags have kind of thrown me for a loop as far as where they should be contained. My best guess so far has been...

```
<?php
if($user['User']['fbcontact']!='')
{
  echo "<li>Facebook: <span>".h('url'=>array,$user['User']['fbcontact'])</span>
</li>";}
?>
```

That keeps throwing off an error with no definitive resolution as to what said error is. I even tried to go old school and just stick `<a href=""></a>` around `$user['User']`['fbcontact']` as a desperate attempt to be creative but that failed as well. I'm pretty certainly that I'm overlooking something incredibly simple, and I've searched almost every article here I can find, looked through the CakePHP Cookbook numerous times, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What errors you get and in which line?

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW on line 146

Comment: which line is 146 in this question?

Comment: echo "<li>Furaffinity: <span>".h(('url'=>array,$user['User']['facontact']))."</span></li>";}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function [h()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/function-h.html)**

> Convenience method for htmlspecialchars.
>   **Syntax**: *h($text|array|object, $double = true, $charset = null)*

Use `h()` inside [$this->Html->link()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink) to create the link and sanitize the input. `h()` uses `htmlspecialchars` to sanitize the input. You can view the [function code here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-function-h.html#160-199).

```
echo "<li>Facebook: <span>". $this->Html->link( h($user['User']['fbcontact']), 'yourURL' ) . "</span></li>";
```

You are getting the syntax error because the value you passed in h() is not a valid array. If you wish to pass array in h() you can do it like this:

```
h( array('url'=> $user['User']['fbcontact']) )
```

Comment: Ah! So close! I have an actual link now! Here's the issue... $user['User']['fbcontact'] delivers an actual URL that the user types in. So the input field states Facebook: and they enter http://www.facebook.com/user/whatever. How do I make the yourURL the very URL that is being displayed?

Comment: This should work: `$this->Html->link( h('Facebook or any text'), $user['User']['fbcontact'] )`. But make sure that the url has `http://` at the start of the url.

Comment: I think perhaps the issue is that I'm not being specific enough... on their profile on my website, once they have submitted everything, my first set of code above displays 

Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/user/12345

THAT is the the physical display that $user['User']['fbcontact'] actually displays. What I need is for that physically displayed contact url to be clickable. Since the information is derived from an SQL database the URL is different on every profile.

Comment: Something like this? `$this->Html->link( $user['User']['fbcontact'], $user['User']['fbcontact'] )`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the quote before `</span>`:

```
echo "<li>Facebook: <span>".h('url'=>array,$user['User']['fbcontact'])."</span></li>";
```

Comment: @LibidinousWonder `h('url'=>array,$user['User']['fbcontact'])`looks fishy. It should be a function that outputs something like `a href="[url]">[text]</a>`, right?
You should also make sure to put `<ul>...</ul>` around all `<li>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you miss double quote and array declaration is incorrect

```
 $User =$user['User']['fbcontact'];
  $array= array();
  $url = $array;
  echo "<li>Facebook: <span>".h($url,$user['User']['fbcontact'])."</span></li>";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also didn't resolve the issue. It's throwing an unexpected syntax error, T_VARIABLE.

Comment: @LibidinousWonder your issue is 'url'=>array this only. why you are passing this format.